# 内包表記にしたい

Tags: python, python3

この `for` 文ですが、内包表記にするにはどうすればよろしいでしょうか？

```
x, n = map(int,input().split())
num = [int(input()) for _ in range(n)]

num1 = 0
for i in num:
    num1 += i
    z = x - num1 
    print(z)
```

Answer (score 3):

Python3.8 以降であれば `:=`(walrus operator/セイウチ演算子) を使って以下の様に書くことができます。

```py
num1 = 0
_ = [print(x - (num1:=num1+i)) for i in num]
```

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。こんな書き方があったんですね！！すごく参考になります

Answer (score 2):

[`itertools.accumulate()`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate)を用いた実装が考えられます。計算結果はリストとして得られるため、print出力は別途調整してください。

```py
import itertools

x, n = map(int,input().split())
num = [int(input()) for _ in range(n)]

z = [x - n for n in itertools.accumulate(num)]
print(z)
```

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。こちらも、ものすごく参考になります！今後参考にして活用していきます！